# Preview multiple drop using react-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I'm trying to implement Dropzone on my app but I can't preview photos if they are drop as a multiple input. If I add them one by one it works fine but if I select multiple only the first one gets rendered.

This is my onDrop function

```
onDropGeneral = (currentGeneralPhoto) => {
 let index;
 for (index = 0; index < currentGeneralPhoto.length; ++index) {
  const file = currentGeneralPhoto[index];
  this.setState({
    previewGeneralPhotos: this.state.previewGeneralPhotos.concat(file)
  });
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    console.log('URL: ', event.target.result);
    this.setState({
      generalPhotos: this.state.generalPhotos.concat([{ base64: event.target.result }])
    });
  };
 }
}
```

and this is my render method:

```
<h2>Dropped files</h2>
{this.state.previewGeneralPhotos.length > 0 ? <div>
  <h2>Preview {this.state.previewGeneralPhotos.length} files...</h2>
  <div>{this.state.previewGeneralPhotos.map((file) => <img src={file.preview} alt="preview failed" />)}</div>
 </div> : null}
 <h2> Upload {this.state.generalPhotos.length} Files </h2>
```

the Upload count is showing the right size of the array but the Preview count only counts the 1st photo dropped

Comment: Care to post you working code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is because `setState` can be asynchronous. You should use the function callback for `setState` as follows in your `onDropGeneral` function:

```
this.setState(({ previewGeneralPhotos }) => ({
  previewGeneralPhotos: previewGeneralPhotos.concat(file)
}))
```

This will make sure you don't accidentally overwrite the previous value of `previewGeneralPhotos` and you actually add to the existing array as you intend.

A couple of other suggestions:

- Make sure your `img` elements have a key.
- I would use an instance of the file reader for the entire Component instead of creating a new one each time your `onDropGeneral` method is called. You could attach an event listener for the 'load' event in `componentDidMount` and remove that listener in `componentWillUnmount`. At the very least, it's probably best to attach that event listener *before* calling `reader.readAsDataURL`.